# I need help understanding these instructions. --interface, polymorphism----

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I will create a LogNode class in which it will contain a log entry and a link to the next LogNode. I a log entry that will work for all the log entry classes.(I will have 3 logEntry classes)To hold these different types of log entries in the LogNode, we will create an interface for the log entries. This interface is called Loggable, and each individual type of log entry will implement this interface.

Thus **the LogNode will contain a field of type Loggable to hold the log entry** (i dont fully understand in the bold) and a field of type LogNode to link to the next node in the log.

I understand that my LogNode class will have a field of type LogNode to link to the next Node. which is,

LogNode nextLink; <-----i get that

what I don't understand is I need a a field of type Loggable to hold the log entry?

so If this was my LogNode class:

public class LogNode{

LogNode nextLink;

Loggable logEntry; <--if this is what it is saying how does this work?

........ } i think i am wrong but my log entries will be strings so how can a field of type Loggable hold a string. so does that also mean i will have a String variable in my Loggable interface. I might be wrong as i dont fully understand this. I would greatly appreciate your input. thanks

Comment: If all your log entries are strings, you do not need Loggable at all. And if this is not just a school exercise, you do not need LogNode, either. All you need is List<String> logs = new LinkedList<String>();

Answer (score 1):

Well :) what you did is a linked list.

So basically a linked-list works like this :

[ ] --> [ ] --> [ ] --> ...

But when it gets interesting, it's when you put something inside the [ ] and that's what you did :

[logEntry] --> [logEntry] --> [logEntry] --> ...

you can put basically what you want inside the [ ], to put information inside every node of your linked-list. And you choose to put a Loggable object inside :)

You talk also about String. It can works also with a String.

[String] --> [String] --> [String] --> ...

But, if you need a linked-list of String in Java, I recommand :

```
LinkedList<String> thisObject = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your log entries are supposed to contain `String`s, you should create your `Loggable` interface that way.

```
public interface Loggable {
    public String logEntry();
}
```

Now you can create the linked list as you mentioned. Your approach and understanding is correct in that part.

```
public class LogNode {

    /**
     * Log entry provider object. (implements Loggable).
     */
    private Loggable loggable;

    /**
     * Link for next node.
     */
    private LogNode next;

    // Constructors, getters etc...
}
```

Hope this helps.